# How to set a connection to insecure on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, influxdb

I've a `Spring` application using the **InfluxDB** lib. The host is a `SSL` (https) connection but I want disable the SSL check only to Influx connection, because the application have others host connections that use SSL. How I can disable the SSL connection only to Influx host?

I've found the questions about disable SSL on `RestTemplate`, but on this case I'm using the Influx lib instead a REST call.

Comment: What do you mean by "the SSL check"? If the InfluxDB instance you're trying to connect to has TLS enabled then you have to connect using TLS (https).  If not then you can use http.

Comment: There are a nginx between it that no have http way. The wish is skip the TLS check.

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean by "skip the TLS check".  If you're using self-signed certificates you can set `insecure_skip_verify = true` as stated here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/security/enable-tls/

Comment: I must set it on the application side.

Comment: What do you mean by "host".

Comment: a host is the host endpoint of influxdb.